# Что означает строчка

Tags: python, numpy

Преподаватель дал учебный код, который мы должны разобрать дома. Но одна строка меня озадачила. В гугле результаты поиска не показали ни один пример применения подобной строки
Сама строка:

```
w=np.random.rand(m,n)0.1-0.05
```

Понятно, что это генерация рандомных чисел в диапазоне от m до n, но что означает 0.1-0.05 - загадка, покрытая тайнами

Comment: в этой строчке ошибка, поэтому сложно сказать, что она должна означать.

Comment: уточняйте условие, тут ошибки

Comment: @Эникейщик на такой мысли и я остановилась. Но если мне не ошибает память, была речь про то, что это числа от -0.05 до 0.05

Comment: @finally видимо вэтом и суть, что преподаватель дал код с ошибкой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`m` и `n` - это **размерность** матрицы (я не знал, но заглянул в [описание функции](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.rand.html))

Матрица размерностью `m x n` случайных чисел в диапазоне `0..1` **умножается** на скаляр `0.1` и вычитается `0.05`, таким образом диапазон становится  `-0.05 ... 0.05`

Умножение потеряно где-то